# How do I add a data object to a JSON object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to add the data `[]` of list 2 to list 1 as children. The desired output is list 3. But with my code I get empty string as values for children. The api call in `_getJsonObject(id,user)` brings list 2.

The code I have looks as follows:

```
var strList = function (){
    var listItems= "";
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8088/api/v1/ui/performance/custom_link_groups?',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(data){
            for (var i = 0; i  < data.data.length; i++){
                data.data[i].children = _getJsonObject(data.data[i].$ID,data.data[i].$userId);
            } 
            listItems = data;
        }
    });
    return listItems;   
}();


function _getJsonObject(id,user){
    var rdata = "";
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8088/api/v1/ui/performance/custom_links?group='+id+'&user='+user,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(data){
            rdata = data.data;
        }
    });
    return rdata;
}
```

**List 1**

```
{
"response_code": 200,
"error_code": "",
"error_message": "",
"status": "SUCCESS",
"row_count": 5,
"data": [
    {
        "ID": "84",
        "groupLabel": "Interface Util",
        "isPrivate": "0",
        "userId": "user1"
    },
    {
        "ID": "85",
        "groupLabel": "Hendrick Test Mweb",
        "isPrivate": "0",
        "userId": "user2"
    },
    {
        "ID": "86",
        "groupLabel": "test",
        "isPrivate": "0",
        "userId": "user4"
    },
    {
        "ID": "87",
        "groupLabel": "Interface Util",
        "isPrivate": null,
        "userId": "user3"
    },
    {
        "ID": "88",
        "groupLabel": "testing",
        "isPrivate": "0",
        "userId": "user5"
    }
],
"meta": ""
```

}

**List 2**

```
{
"response_code": 200,
"error_code": "",
"error_message": "",
"status": "SUCCESS",
"row_count": 2,
"data": [
    {
        "ID": "53",
        "attributeId": "2194242",
        "groupId": "85",
        "isSummary": null,
        "label": "DEV-SUPPORT-PC, DEV-SUPPORT-PC : Uptime",
        "rrdGraphGroup": null
    },
    {
        "ID": "54",
        "attributeId": "2255447||2255453",
        "groupId": "85",
        "isSummary": null,
        "label": "DEV-SUPPORT-PC, Intel(R)%2082578DC%20Gigabit%20Network%20Connection%20 : Utilization",
        "rrdGraphGroup": "Utilization"
    }
],
"meta": ""
```

}

**List 3**

```
{
"response_code": 200,
"error_code": "",
"error_message": "",
"status": "SUCCESS",
"row_count": 5,
"data": [
    {
        "ID": "84",
        "groupLabel": "Interface Util",
        "isPrivate": "0",
        "userId": "user1",
        "children": ""
    },
    {
        "ID": "85",
        "groupLabel": "Hendrick Test Mweb",
        "isPrivate": "0",
        "userId": "user2",
        "chlidren": [
                    {
                    "ID": "53",
                    "attributeId": "2194242",
                    "groupId": "85",
                    "isSummary": null,
                    "label": "DEV-SUPPORT-PC, DEV-SUPPORT-PC : Uptime",
                    "rrdGraphGroup": null
                    },
                    {
                    "ID": "54",
                    "attributeId": "2255447||2255453",
                    "groupId": "85",
                    "isSummary": null,
                    "label": "DEV-SUPPORT-PC, Intel(R)%2082578DC%20Gigabit%20Network%20Connection%20 : Utilization",
                    "rrdGraphGroup": "Utilization"
                    }
                    ]
    },
    {
        "ID": "86",
        "groupLabel": "test",
        "isPrivate": "0",
        "userId": "user4",
        "children": ""
    },
    {
        "ID": "87",
        "groupLabel": "Interface Util",
        "isPrivate": null,
        "userId": "user3",
        "children": ""
    },
    {
        "ID": "88",
        "groupLabel": "testing",
        "isPrivate": "0",
        "userId": "user5",
        "children": ""
    }
],
"meta": ""
}
```

Comment: You need to use callbacks and execute them where the ajax call has ended, otherwise you are returning from _getJsonObject before the ajax call has ended. Use a callback as thrid paramter of that function and in the sucess callback of the ajax request call to that callback with the data.data.

Comment: Even with `async: false` the `return` statements are executed _before_ the AJAX callbacks are.

Answer (score 0):

```
var strList = function (callback){
var listItems= "";
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8088/api/v1/ui/performance/custom_link_groups?',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function(data){
        for (var i = 0; i  < data.data.length; i++){
            _getJsonObject(data.data[i].$ID,data.data[i].$userId,         

             function(data)
             {
               data.data[i].children = data;
             });
            } 
           callback(data);
        }
    });
    return listItems;   
}();


function _getJsonObject(id,user, callback){
    var rdata = "";
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8088/api/v1/ui/performance/custom_links?group='+id+'&user='+user,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(data){
           callback(data.data);
        }
    });
    return rdata;
}
```